# Font attributes within single line

Tags: css

I was testing one of my apps on chromium and in order to explain my question properly I made a simple fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/A3zLC/

Firefox turned up blank, but chrome rendered the following....

```
font: italic normal bold 14px/50px arial;
```

Which font property does the `normal` value come from?

Comment: Your question is a little confusing. Does this help? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font

Comment: I didn't know there was a font-variant attribute. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `normal` value in this case is coming from the `font-variant` property.

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font